Proving that $\prod_{g\in G}g^2=e$ for finite, abelian $G$. Why is the condition of finite cardinality stated in the exercise?
In my algebra book, there is the following exercise:
Exercise. Let $(G,\ast)$ be a finite abelian group with the neutral element $e\in G$. Prove, that $\prod_{g\in G}g^2=e.$
My solution to the problem is the following:
Solution. $\prod_{g\in G}g^2=\prod_{g\in G}g\ast g\stackrel{\substack{\forall g\in G\exists g^{-1}}\in G,\\
(g^{-1})^{-1}=g\ \forall g\in G,\\
\text{commutativity}}{=}\prod_{g\in G}g\ast g^{-1}=\prod_{g\in G}e=e.$

My question: Why is the condition of finite cardinality stated in the exercise? Maybe my solution is incorrect or incomplete?


What would an infinite product mean?

Why does your second equality hold?

To give a concrete example expanding on Steve D's comment: Compare to $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} (n+n)$.  What would this infinite summation mean?

For the equality in the middle you need some more steps, to be precise, $$\prod(gg)=\left(\prod g\right)\left(\prod g\right)=\left(\prod g\right)\left(\prod g^{-1}\right)=\prod (gg^{-1})=\prod e=e\ .$$ (All products are over $g\in G$.)

Merely asking what an infinite product would mean does not constitute an answer.  It's an appeal to incredulity.  There needs to be an explanation.

@AndreaMori, but integer powers distribute over (finite) multiplication, so long as that multiplication is associative and commutative, and inverses of all product terms exist.

@Shaun, that's probably why it's a comment, rather than an answer.

@AndreaMori Where are those $|G|^2$ factors in $$\left(\prod_{g\in G}g\right)*\left(\prod_{g\in G}g\right)\ ?$$

@AndreaMori, I see what you're getting at now. I thought you were saying that they weren't (necessarily) equal.

In an abelian group $G$ (multiplicative notation) the set
$$
K=\{g^2\,|\,g\in G\}
$$
is a subqroup, in fact the image of the homomorphism $q:G\rightarrow G$, $q(g)=g^2$.
Thus, when $G$ is finite,
$$
\prod_{g\in G}g^2=\left(\prod_{\gamma\in K}\gamma\right)^c=1\qquad\qquad (\ast)
$$
where $c=|\ker(q)|$, because multiplying up all elements in a finite abelian group gives $1$ (I assume this is well-known).

The finiteness condition on $G$ is necessary to make the summation $(\ast)$ defined since in a group with no extra-structure infinite sums are meaningless.
It can be noted that there may be situations where although $G$ is infinite the subgroup $K$ is finite. Consider for instance the group
$$
G=\prod_{{\cal I}}\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z},
$$
the product of an arbitrary set of copies of the group of order $2$, where $K=\{0\}$. In such a situation the sum $\sum_{\gamma\in K}\gamma$ makes sense (and equals $e_G$) but the factor $c$ is not finite.

Although this solves the exercise, it doesn't answer the question (completely).

@Shaun I added an observation about infinite groups

It's easier to see what's happening in additive notation here. Then you're asking if
\begin{equation}
\sum_{g\in G} 2g = 0
\end{equation}
When $G$ is finite, we can pull that $2$ out, to get
\begin{equation}
2\sum_{g\in G}g = \sum_{g\in G}g + \sum_{g\in G} g = \sum_{g\in G} g + \sum_{g\in G}-g = \sum_{g\in G} (g-g) = 0
\end{equation}
It's instructive to see how much of the above relies on $G$ being finite. For example, pulling out the $2$ relies on the distributive property. Collecting like terms in the last sum also relies on being able to reorder the sum without changing its value. To see what can go wrong, try reading the above sequence of equations from right to left for the group $\mathbb{R}$. The first equality might seem believable. What about the second?
Believability is a weak argument here. But it hints at the fact some additional structure is needed to make these things well-defined. Indeed, the definition of an Abelian group relies on a binary operation, together with finite associativity. It thus leaves infinite sums undefined.

Take the disjoint union $G=\{e\}\cup A \cup B$, where $A$ is the set of elements of $G$ not equal to their own inverse, and $B$ is the set of non identity elements equal to their own inverse.
Then $\prod_{g \in A} g = e$, since every element of $A$ is paired up with own inverse, and $\prod_{g \in B} g*g = e$, since each $g \in B$ has $g*g = e$. In particular $\prod_{g \in G} g*g = e$.
We might add that for some examples, e.g. G a product of cyclic groups of odd order, the set B is empty, and we can improve the result to $\prod_{g \in G} g = e$.

Although this solves the exercise, it doesn't answer the question.

Despite the edit, this still doesn't answer the question.

Apologies, Shaun, I hadn't read the question carefully. Regarding your question, how would you even define the infinite product over a group? For example if your group was $\mathbb{Z}$, how would you define $\sum_{a \in \mathbb{Z}} a$?

It's okay.  (It's not my question.  I have thoughts along those lines as an answer, but I feel that even that doesn't fully articulate why - it feels like an argument from incredulity.)
